# Avoiding Firebase duplicate results in Cannot read property 'apps'

Tags: typescript, firebase, next.js

I am trying to use Firebase in a TypeScript/NextJS project but I've been unsuccessful in getting it to work.  I am able to import it and initialize an app:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig= ({
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
});

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

However, when I reload the page I get this error:

`FirebaseError: Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app).`

To mitigate this I replaced,

`firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);`

with

```
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
 } else {
    firebase.app();
 }
```

but now I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.

Intellisense on `apps` says `Property 'apps' does not exist on type`, but I don't know what to do with this information.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What versions of the Firebase SDKs are you using? If you've never done this before, you should be able to find that from looking at the dependencies in your `package.json`.

Comment: I seem to be using 9.0.0-beta.1.  Should I change to a different version?

Comment: The syntax you're using is for 8.x and earlier versions of the Firebase SDKs, so I recommend using those. Version 9 introduces a completely different, modular syntax - as shown in @jnpdx's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In version 9**, you should be able to use `getApps` for the test instead:

```
import { getApps, initializeApp } from "firebase/app"

if (!getApps().length) initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v9/app.md#getapps

Comment: const firebaseApp = !getApps().length ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : getApp();

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you're using is for 8.x and earlier versions of the Firebase SDKs, so I recommend using those. Version 9 introduces a completely different, modular syntax - as shown in @jnpdx's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67576792).

Comment: Brilliant, I'll do that.  Thanks very much for the clarification!